# Selling to managers / making things easy for users - on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I probably need to make a fundamental change to the company network that will affect all of my users, potentially making things less convenient than before.  There is a well-known process for making this change, including some very good answers on Server Fault already.

But I need to

1. sell the change to managers
2. minimize the increase in inconvenience to users, especially the ones who  like convenience (see requirement 1).

There are bound to be decisions made in planning and presenting the change that increase the chance of success (i.e. users don't show up at my door with pitchforks and torches).   This is clearly a subjective question and the best answers would come from people who had been through the change already.

In case you're wondering, the actual question would ask about renaming an Active Directory domain from something succinct (but now deprecated) to something long and tedious (but with less chance of trouble down the road).  AFAIC "Why" is beyond the scope of both the actual question and this meta-question.

I understand you may think I want to ask a duplicated question, but this includes the squishy topic of Not Triggering a Revolution.

Is it a good fit for Server Fault?

Comment: This is as much a part of our job as actually renaming the domain, so I don't really have a problem with it.

Comment: What @MichaelHampton said, but for the less technical side of this issue, there is also [workplace.se]

Comment: @Sven There is that. I suspect discussions of "how to couch specific terms so that peoples' eyes don't glaze over" might be better answered here.